# How to *always* log exceptions and stacktraces in django with DEBUG = False

Tags: django, logging, django-2.0

How do I set `DEBUG = False`, but ensure exceptions (wherever they may be thrown) are properly logged, including a stack trace.

Here is my logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'},
        'require_debug_true': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'}
    },
    'formatters': {
        'django.server': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[%(server_time)s] %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
        'django.server': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'django.server',
            'level': 'INFO'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'level': 'ERROR'
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['console']
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.security': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no default config where all exceptions are being recorded in a log file, there are couple of options for you to try out in django:

1. Configure the [ADMINS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#admins), to receive emails about all exceptions in your site
2. You can write a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware), that has a process_exception method that writes to the logger with `logger.error('Exception info)`

Comment: the exception passed into process_exception does not seem to have access to the stack trace